# WPF Binding data to datagrid leads memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, datagrid

I have a WPF application which gets data from some serial device and  locally i am creating database which has all the data.  i have a timer which periodically update data to datagrid by using ResetBindings().

```
data.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
data.ResetBindings();
data.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
```

Timer will update the data to datagrid periodically which leads to memory leak. i tried comment out above part in timer then my application is taking stable memory.

is there any way to solve the issue?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There's no such thing as `ResetBindings()` in WPF. Close-voting.

Comment: You should be using a `DataGrid` to house a `ListView` and set the listview's ItemsSource to the List<Object> that has been refreshed from timer executing a repository 'select'.

Comment: @Andrew, Yes by doing this my application is consuming huge memory some times leads to application crash

Comment: @user3274485 if you want relevant answers, please post relevant code. Your current question is completely unclear because that is NOT WPF code.